# Using melt with matrix or data.frame gives different output

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, reshape2, melt

Consider the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
M = matrix(rnorm(9), ncol = 3)
dimnames(M) = list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3])

print(M)
           A          B         C
A -0.6264538  1.5952808 0.4874291
B  0.1836433  0.3295078 0.7383247
C -0.8356286 -0.8204684 0.5757814

melt(M)

  Var1 Var2      value
1    A    A -0.6264538
2    B    A  0.1836433
3    C    A -0.8356286
4    A    B  1.5952808
5    B    B  0.3295078
6    C    B -0.8204684
7    A    C  0.4874291
8    B    C  0.7383247
9    C    C  0.5757814
```

If i call `melt` using a `data.frame`, i get a different result:

```
DF = data.frame(M)

melt(DF)

  variable      value
1        A -0.6264538
2        A  0.1836433
3        A -0.8356286
4        B  1.5952808
5        B  0.3295078
6        B -0.8204684
7        C  0.4874291
8        C  0.7383247
9        C  0.5757814
```

I found the docs a little bit confusing on this, so anyone can help me understand this behavior? Can i get the first result using a data.frame?

Comment: Yes, but i found it odd that the same matrix/data.frame gives a different result, i couldn't figure out the reason yet.

Comment: I edited the values, not it uses set.seed(1).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The basic reason is that there are different `methods` for `melt`, which you can see by running `methods("melt")`. Most of these can be accessed by, say, `reshape2:::melt.matrix` or `reshape2:::melt.data.frame`, which can send you on your hunt for figuring out exactly why the results are different.

But, to summarize what you will find, basically, `melt.matrix` will end up doing something like:

```
cbind(expand.grid(dimnames(M)), value = as.vector(M))
#   Var1 Var2      value
# 1    A    A -0.6264538
# 2    B    A  0.1836433
# 3    C    A -0.8356286
# 4    A    B  1.5952808
# 5    B    B  0.3295078
# 6    C    B -0.8204684
# 7    A    C  0.4874291
# 8    B    C  0.7383247
# 9    C    C  0.5757814
```

... while `melt.data.frame` will end up doing something like this:

```
N <- data.frame(M)
data.frame(var1 = rep(names(N), each = nrow(N)), value = unlist(unname(N)))
#   var1      value
# 1    A -0.6264538
# 2    A  0.1836433
# 3    A -0.8356286
# 4    B  1.5952808
# 5    B  0.3295078
# 6    B -0.8204684
# 7    C  0.4874291
# 8    C  0.7383247
# 9    C  0.5757814
```

Of course, the actual functions do a lot more error checking and are designed to let you conveniently specify which columns should be melted and so on.

Note that the `data.frame` method doesn't make use of the `rownames`, so as mentioned in the comments, to get the same result with the `data.frame` method, you'll have to add them in to the `melt` command.