# tidyr::gather vs. reshape2::melt on matrices

Tags: r, matrix, reshape2, tidyr

I've been a long time user of `reshape2::melt` in a rather non-standard way: I'm running numeric experiments and get a matrix as a result. I then melt it and produce some images.

Inspired by the [similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536251/comparing-gather-tidyr-to-melt-reshape2) between `reshape2` and `tidyr`, I'm now trying to achieve identical output on objects of class matrix. No luck so far:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix(runif(6), 3)
mat2 <- mat
colnames(mat2) <- letters[1:2]
rownames(mat2) <- letters[3:5]

melt(mat)
melt(mat2)
gather(mat) # fails
gather(mat2) # fails
```

Note that `melt` is smart and keeps `dimnames` if they are present. I've learnt [how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264737/using-melt-with-matrix-or-data-frame-gives-different-output), so I can potentially add the following function to the method dispatch:

```
gather.matrix <- function(mat) {
  if (is.null(dimnames(mat))) {
    grid <- expand.grid(seq.int(nrow(mat)), seq.int(ncol(mat)))
  } else {
    grid <- expand.grid(dimnames(mat))
  }
  cbind(grid, value = as.vector(mat))
}

all.equal(melt(mat), 
          gather.matrix(mat))
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(melt(mat2), 
          gather.matrix(mat2))
#[1] TRUE
```

But the question is, can I force `gather` act in the same way as `melt` in my case? Is there any combination of parameters that would produce the desired output on `mat` and `mat2`?

Comment: Considering that "tidyr is designed for use in conjunction with dplyr" and that "dplyr" is "focussed on tools for working with data frames", I think you might be better off sticking with `melt` (inasmuch as `gather` seems to be a wrapper for `melt` anyway).

Comment: @AnandaMahto I'm inclined to do so indeed, just wondering if I'm missing something obvious :)

Comment: If a `gather` method is really needed, I guess save yourself the rewrite and just do `gather.matrix <- reshape2:::melt.matrix`.... :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto That's neat, haven't thought of that :) These two comments of yours sum up to a decent answer, would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps a better answer will emerge, but in the meantime, I'll convert my comments to an answer:

Quoting from the README to "tidyr":

> Note that tidyr is designed for use in conjunction with dplyr, so you should always load both.

... and from the README to "dplyr":

> dplyr is the next iteration of plyr, focussed on tools for working with data frames (hence the `d` in the name).

As such, it *sort of* makes sense to not have methods for matrices.

---

Since `gather` already wraps around `melt`, if you really wanted a `matrix` method, you can save yourself writing a custom function and just do something like:

```
gather.matrix <- reshape2:::melt.matrix
```