# how to transform this dataframe to long format

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
a <- c("Lilo","Chops","Henmans")
a <- cbind(a,c(0.1,0.5,0.25),c(0.2,0.3,0.65),c(0.7,0.2,0.1))
colnames(a) <- c("market","Product A","Product B","Product C")
```

and would like to melt it:

```
b <- melt(a, varnames = c("market"))
```

this gives the following:

```
> b
   market        NA   value
1       1    market    Lilo
2       2    market   Chops
3       3    market Henmans
4       1 Product A     0.1
5       2 Product A     0.5
6       3 Product A    0.25
7       1 Product B     0.2
8       2 Product B     0.3
9       3 Product B    0.65
10      1 Product C     0.7
11      2 Product C     0.2
12      3 Product C     0.1
>
```

However, want I'm looking for is

```
> b
    market        NA value
4     Lilo Product A   0.1
5    Chops Product A   0.5
6  Henmans Product A  0.25
7     Lilo Product B   0.2
8    Chops Product B   0.3
9  Henmans Product B  0.65
10    Lilo Product C   0.7
11   Chops Product C   0.2
12 Henmans Product C   0.1
```

How do I achieve this using melt?

Comment: The values in a are not numeric. The reason is that in R a matrix can only save values of one type: So in your case mixing numeric and character (column market) makes the matrix numeric.
Maybe you want to use `data.table`'s instead. Read in your data as follows:
`DF <- data.frame(c("Lilo","Chops","Henmans"), c(0.1,0.5,0.25),c(0.2,0.3,0.65),c(0.7,0.2,0.1)); 
colnames(DF) <- c("market","Product A","Product B","Product C")`

Then use `melt(DF)`

Comment: This is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264737/using-melt-with-matrix-or-data-frame-gives-different-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `rownames` instead of a seperate column `market`. This way you get a numeric matrix and you can use `melt` very simple as follows:

```
a <- cbind(c(0.1,0.5,0.25),c(0.2,0.3,0.65),c(0.7,0.2,0.1))
rownames(a) <- c("Lilo","Chops","Henmans")
colnames(a) <- c("Product A","Product B","Product C")
```

**a** now looks like this:

```
        Product A Product B Product C
Lilo         0.10      0.20       0.7
Chops        0.50      0.30       0.2
Henmans      0.25      0.65       0.1
```

You can access the "markets" by using `rownames(a)`.

Melt now works as follows (which uses `melt.array` to perform the reshape):

```
melt(a)
     Var1      Var2 value
1    Lilo Product A  0.10
2   Chops Product A  0.50
3 Henmans Product A  0.25
4    Lilo Product B  0.20
5   Chops Product B  0.30
6 Henmans Product B  0.65
7    Lilo Product C  0.70
8   Chops Product C  0.20
9 Henmans Product C  0.10
```